# Know if validation was already called

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongoid3

How to know if a model was already validated?

```
u = User.new
u.name = "Ralph"
u.valid? # => true
u.validated? # => false
```

I want to prevent too much queries on geocoding.

Comment: Skip in what context? What do you mean by skip? What are you geocoding? Can you post your `user.rb`?

Comment: if just do `u.save` it will validate only once e return `false` if not valid.

Comment: Minus three is heavy... I wanna know if this model was already "validated". It should not hit the validation process again. For example ```before_validation :geocode``` will be hitted every time when my model gets validated. But I wanna hit them only once to save my google lookup contingent. So I thought there is a "validated?" method to show me if the validation process was already done. I hope it's clearer now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have `before_validation :geocode` callback you can improve your `geocode` method to cache heavy code results this way:

```
def geocode
  @geocode_results ||= {}
  # suppose geocoding depends on `lat_lon` attribute
  @geocode_results[lat_lon] ||= begin
    # Your heavy code here
  end
end
```

Caching as hash value lets redo geocoding when lat_lon changes.